# convert php/js website to mobile...create new website?

Tags: php, mobile, web

I have a complicated php/mysql/js website.  I want to create a mobile version.  Based on reading on the web, I think it has to be a dedicated stripped down site like m.google.com or m.yahoo.com, not a responsive one as the current site has multiple columns and images.  (It already works on a mobile browser, but strains the eyes and is far from optimized.)

I gather the ideal version would be to have one set of files and just swqp in a different stylessheet after detecting a mobile browser.  However, the site was not built for that and that's not a realistic option.  Site also is no built with templates.

On the other hand, I don't want to rewrite all the logic and dbase queries.

The two options I can think of are as follows:

Option 1: One set of files ie one website.  I could detect for mobile browser and set a session variable.  Then on every page, I would check for the mobile session variable and if present, display markup that is optimized for the handheld.

Option 2: Copy the website files to a separate directory such as mobile.  Then redo the markup in those files so it is optimized for the handheld.

Would I still be able to do Option 1 and have the website have its own subdomain as in m.site.com

What is considered best practice for mobile website when just swapping out a different stylesheet or using a separate template is not an option.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not a good format for SO.  I will say however that there is not hard and fast "best way" to do things. The "best way" for you might depend on what is most important. Do you have schedule dates to meet?  How much work to you want to put into the refactoring? If you are dealing with a client or internal customer, how much time/money are they willing to invest in this change?  Do they have specific requirements around what the mobile site should be?  How do these requirements lend themselves to reuse of existing code? Just too many variables to get into here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely convinced that you need separate markup, then best practice would normally be to first **separate your business logic from the presentation layer** so that you can reuse the same backend logic, and dynically serve a different frontend view/template. PHP frameworks like Zend Framework, Codeignitor, Symphony, CakePHP (and a multitude of others) make this relatively easy.

As for whether you use a subdomain (m.mysite.com) or a session variable, either way can work well. In PHP you can check the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to see if the 'm' subdomain is being used, or just as easily check a session variable.